# Conditional comparing differences in DF's while ignoring a diagonal

Tags: r

To start, I have two large square N x N data frames of equal dimensions. These data frames happen to be binary adjacency matrices, with all axes being identical to each other, where 0 for a cell value represents two counties that are not adjacent to each other, and where 1 for a cell value represents counties that are adjacent. These dataframes are being created by two separate programs. DF1 is being created by a program that is classifying a geography as being adjacent to itself, whereas the program creating DF2 isn't classifying a geography as being adjacent to itself. This leads to DF1 having a diagonal of 1 values throughout the DF from the top left to the bottom right boundaries of the DF, whereas DF2 has 0 values for this diagonal.

With this known, the issue I am running into is that I am trying to create a script which ignores these differences in how the DF's are treating the diagonal. I would much appreciate help in creating a conditional script that will compare these DF's, ignoring differences in the top left to bottom right diagonal, that will output a TRUE if all observations in a column are the same between the two DF's other than the diagonal, and FALSE if not all observations in a column are the same between the two DF's other than the diagonal?

Hopefully this has been clear, I'll be here poking away at the issue if anyone would like clarification - thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you just enforce the diagonals to be the same, with, for instance `diag(DF1) <- 0` or  `diag(DF2) <- 1`

Comment: Great idea - I think that'll probably fix my issue entirely. Always seems to be a simple solution to my seemingly complicated problems - haha. Thank you very much.